# prevent image overlap with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with images overlapping each other when the browser window is resized. I feel like fixing it may have something to do with the `z-index` function, but I'm not certain as I am not very skilled with CSS.

Here is my CSS:

```
    body {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300;
}

#bottomleft_picture {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    /* bottom left */
}
#topright_picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    /* top right */
}
#bottomright_picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    /* bottom right*/
}
#topleft_picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 50%;
    clear: both;
    /* top left */
}
#topleft_inner_box {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.4;
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#topright_inner_box {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.4;
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 35%;
    right: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#bottomleft_inner_box {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.4;
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#bottomright_inner_box {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.4;
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 40%;
    right: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- add logo here -->
    <div id="bottomleft_picture">
            <div id="bottomleft_inner_box">
            </div>
            <img src="menu.jpg">

    </div>
    <div id="topright_picture">
        <div id="topright_inner_box">
        </div>
        <img src="welcome.jpg">
        </div>
    <div id="bottomright_picture">
        <div id="bottomright_inner_box">
        </div>
        <img src="contact.jpg">

    </div>
    <div id="topleft_picture">
         <div id="topleft_inner_box">
         </div>
        <img src="news.jpg">

    </div>

<!-- add footer -->
</body>

</html>
```

Notice when the window is resized, some of the photos eventually begin to overlap the others. I am trying to make it a more responsive layout that can work on (most) size windows. Any insight into what I can do is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It has everything to do with your use of position absolute and fixed.

Comment: Please refer CSS positioning tutorials to understand how it works. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp , http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position . Your problem lies how the images are positioned

Comment: you're saying I need to make them fixed and not absolute?

Comment: The way I understand, you want 8 images to be layed out on a 4 by 2   grid style?

Comment: @Sai: yes, the slightly transparent divs will eventually contain links.

Comment: **zindex** is used to _prioritize the view of overlapped objects_ **not** _to prevent overlap_

Comment: There are **much** better methods of layout than positioning - [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)